# Firefox is killing the formatting of my site

Tags: html, css, firefox

The website is [www.roshankrishnan.com](http://www.roshankrishnan.com)

It appears to be fine in Chrome, IE, and Safari, but for some reason Firefox messes up the alignment of my navigation bar so the words are not correctly placed in the white bar. I can supply code if needed, but I don't even really know where to begin with this, as I'm sure if I edit my code it'll affect the appearance of my site in other browsers.

Comment: _"I can supply code if needed"_ Yes please.

Comment: in chromium(ubuntu) it is not vertically centered inside the navbar too...

Comment: well... it looks the same for me on chrome and firefox.. use a `reset.css`

Comment: Alignment is the same in Firefox, Chrome and IE for me.

Comment: It's not Firefox's fault you use deprecated tags and don't know how to write valid HTML:  http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=www.roshankrishnan.com&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: Duly noted. Will fix the HTML errors.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try adding a reset script to your css; e.g. [this one](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)

This will reset all values to default and override any mark-up the browser adds.

Comment: You cannot fix [deprecated and malformed HTML](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=www.roshankrishnan.com&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) with a CSS reset.

Comment: I've fixed my HTML and CSS so they are valid and added the reset script, and after a little bit of tweaking it did the trick. Thank you both very much.